# Google Firebase Error(Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing Server with Firebase.

I had copied Google Developer's Video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0&index=2&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM).

It works well, but on log there is an error:

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

It says function returned `undefined`, but I make `function` return a `promise` `set``

How can I solve this?

```
function sanitize(s) {
    var sanitizedText = s;
    console.log('sanitize params: ', sanitizedText);
    sanitizedText = sanitizedText.replace(/\bstupid\b/ig, "wonderful");
    return sanitizedText;
}
exports.sanitizePost = functions.database
    .ref('/posts/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const post = event.data.val();
        if (post.sanitized) return;

        console.log('Sanitizing new post', event.params.pushId);
        console.log(post);
        post.sanitized = true;
        post.title = sanitize(post.title);
        post.body = sanitize(post.body);
        return event.data.ref.set(post); 
    })
```

I'm beginner of Firebase, Nodejs.

Comment: Try `if (post.sanitized) return true;`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: This post has been getting a lot of views.  In a comment from AaronJo on my answer below , he shares that Firebase Support indicated the change requiring a Promise or scalar return value was intentional and will remain.  Can you share any insights regarding why the change was made?  What are the benefits?  When a non-Promise value is returned, does the value have any meaning?

Comment: When you explicitly return a value, it is clear that the function is done. When you explicitly return a promise, it's clear that the function needs to remain active until the promise is resolved/rejected. When you don't return a value, it is not clear what state the function is in.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any chance https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions could be updated? It directs people to just "return;" still, which confused me for a bit.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong on that page, the only "return" instruction is "Terminate a synchronous function with a `return;` statement.", which is for *synchronous* functions, where it is correct afaik.This question was about an asynchronous function, which had a missing return value.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As Frank indicates in his comment on your post, the return statement that is producing the warning is this one:

```
if (post.sanitized) return;
```

The warning can be silenced by returning a dummy value (e.g. null, false, 0).  The value is not used.

Earlier versions of Cloud Functions did not complain when a function exited using a return statement with no value.  That explains why you see `return;` in the video you linked and in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  The comment on the question by Firebaser Frank van Pufeelen, explains why the change was made.

The simplest way to eliminate the warning is to add a return value, as Frank suggested:

```
if (post.sanitized) return 0;
```

Another option is to change the trigger from `onWrite()` to `onCreate()`.  Then the function will not be invoked when the post is sanitized and the check that produces the warning is not needed:

```
exports.sanitizePost = functions.database
    .ref('/test/{pushId}')
    .onCreate(event => {  // <= changed from onWrite()
        const post = event.data.val();
        //if (post.sanitized) return; // <= no longer needed

        console.log('Sanitizing new post', event.params.pushId);
        console.log(post);
        //post.sanitized = true; // <= not needed when trigger is onCreate()
        post.title = sanitize(post.title);
        post.body = sanitize(post.body);
        return event.data.ref.set(post);
    });
```

Comment: Will this check be removed any time soon? Otherwise we'd have to change a lot of code to silence those error warnings in the logs.

Comment: @AaronJo: Contact Firebase Support: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: From what I was told by the firebase support it sounds like things are going to remain this way.

Comment: @AaronJo:  Thanks for sharing the response from Firebase Support.  Not clear to me what the benefit of requiring a return value is.

Comment: It's not clear to me either. I had to add `return 0;` to the end of a function just to get rid of this log error. I'd really like to know what the benefit is for having to add this (to me) extraneous line of code. Maybe @frank-van-puffelen or someone else from the Firebase team could explain the logic of it?

Comment: @thoragio: See FvP's new comment on the question.

Comment: @BobSnyder Awesome. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error for attempting to read a document using `.get()` which returns a promise.

I found out in the [official Firebase YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/d9GrysWH1Lc) that to resolve this error, I needed to **return the promise** line of code. Check **minute 4:18** in the tutorial linked video [https://youtu.be/d9GrysWH1Lc]

Also, as a side note, what lead me to the tutorial solution is when I noticed in the function logs did actually log valid values but only after the function is closed, even though the error says the result was undefined.

Comment: The tutorial link no longer works unfortunately :-/

Comment: Click on the hyperlink to the video where I typed “official Firebase YouTube tutorial”

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @bob-snyder said, your problem is that your returning `undefined` under a condition.

```
if (post.sanitized) return;
```

My suggestion is to use a **single exit point**, which is a common tip when programming. [Article](https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/coding-tips/coding-tip-have-a-single-exit-point/).

#### Example

```
// code...
const SUCCESS_CODE = 0;

exports.sanitizePost = functions.database
    .ref('/posts/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const post = event.data.val();

        let response = Promise.resolve(SUCCESS_CODE);

        if (!post.sanitized) {
            console.log('Sanitizing new post', event.params.pushId);
            console.log(post);
            post.sanitized = true;
            post.title = sanitize(post.title);
            post.body = sanitize(post.body);
            response = event.data.ref.set(post); 
        }

        return response;
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that when the trigger handler is an async function, the warning isn't raised even if we don't have an explicit `return` statement.

When the trigger handler is a sync function, we'd need an explicit return statement to silence the warning, like [like it was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47145880/1145905)
in the accepted answer.

That is, if we rewrote

```
exports.updatePost = functions.firestore
.document("posts/{postId}")
.onUpdate(async (snap, context) => { /* async handler*/
  ...
});
```

to

```
exports.updatePost = functions.firestore
.document("posts/{postId}")
.onUpdate((snap, context) => { /* sync handler*/
  ...
});
```

We'd need to do `return 0;` or similar inside the sync handler.

In any case, for async, it's probably a good idea to explicitly return a promise on the async handler, as [advised on the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.